# Yii Custom Validation - Class Validate contains 1 abstract method

Tags: php, yii

I have some validation methods that I need to use for multiple models. For example validation of phone numbers can be shared across multiple models.

I understand from http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/ I can create an extension that can be used by multiple models, for example:

```
array('phone', 'ext.Validate.Validate'),
```

I have modified this line a few times and can confirm it is hitting the right file.

With the following in Validate.php

```
class Validate
```

I get the error `Call to undefined method Validate::applyTo()`, therefore I have changed it to

```
class Validate extends CValidator
```

As suggested by the link above, however I now get the error:

```
Class Validate contains 1 abstract method
```

Here is the file as it stands:

```
<?php

class Validate extends CValidator
{
    public function phone($phone)
    {
        if(!ctype_digit($phone))
        {
            $this->addError($phone, Yii::t('flash','flash.not_authorised',array('{attribute}'=>$phone)).' '.ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $phone)).' field');
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can have a shared validation between multiple methods using the above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve this.

I found the following after a few hours of searching http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/

The main issue is tat you need the following method in your class, when extending CValidator:

```
protected function validateAttribute($object,$attribute)
{

}
```

Here is the model code (yii/protected/extension/Validate/Validate.php)

```
array('phone', 'ext.Validate.Validate'),
```

Here is the class code:

```
<?php

class Validate extends CValidator
{
    protected function validateAttribute($object,$attribute)
    {
        self::{$attribute."Validation"}($object,$attribute);   
    }


    protected function phoneValidation($object,$attribute)
    {
        if(!empty($object->$attribute))
        {
            if(!ctype_digit($object->$attribute))
            {
                 $this->addError($object,$attribute,Yii::t('app','validation.telephon_failed',array('{attribute}'=>ucwords($attribute))));
            }
        }
    }
}
```